# GAE not loading properties file

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created an app-engine app where in I am loading properties files using Spring based configuration  and using it in  as "${app.id}". When I run my app, all properties are getting loaded properly and my program works like charm but when I deploy the same application in Google App-Engine, I noticed that properties are not getting loaded and am getting null pointer exception. Does anyone has any pointer for this issue. I have googled a lot but not getting any correct solutions. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your **applicationContext.xml**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/test.properties" />
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. As mentioned above  this configuration work when I execute locally but when I upload it in app engine this doesn't work

Comment: @PradeepSharma you must have some configuration issues, please add your applicationContext.xml, spring-servlet.xml and web.xml.